# How to select multiple Build Target in Eclipse for Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, build, target

I am reading Teach Yourself Android Application Development in 24 Hours, in Hour 6, it asks me to create a new Android Project with:

Build target: Android 2.1 + Google APIs

However, I can only select Android 2.1 OR Google APIs, not both, under the list of build targets, when I hover above Google APIs, it says Android + Google APIs, does it mean if I select Google APIs as build target, it will include Android (which version?)? But what if I want to use, say, "Real3D Add-On" as well as "Google APIs", as there is no way to select multiple targets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can only select one target in eclipse.

If you select Google APIS it will be for the Android API version for the Google API listed (and below). If you want the LG Real3D Addon target (I'm guessing it's LG) then it will be for whatever API version it shows.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to use Google API as well as Real3D Addon?